# Define JSON for requirement

Tags: javascript, json

I need to define a JSON for the following requirement;

```
Company company : Object (Name, Id)
User user – Object (Name, Age)
List<CustomObj> serviceList  
    o   Service service
    o   String mode
    o   Boolean flag1
    o   Boolean flag2
```

I have tried something like;

```
{
  Company : { "name" : "Company1", "id" : 123 },
  User : {"name" : ["PV","PR", "DM", "TN"], "age" : null},
  serviceList : 
  {
  Service: {},
  "mode" : null,
  "flag1" : null;
  "flag2" : null
  }
}
```

The reason I have null values in a few places is because there are 2 modes; Create and Edit..

So in Create mode, some of the fields would have null values...

But you can let me know generically if it is correct?

Comment: "I need.." is not a good way to present your question. Please tell us what have you done so far, we will take it from there.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer before your edit, see below for a follow-up:

`company` looks like a simple object:

```
{"Name": "the name", "Id": "the ID"}
```

As does `user`:

```
{"Name": "the name", "Age": "the age"}
```

`serviceList` looks like an array of objects:

```
[
    {
     "service": {},
     "mode": "the mode",
     "flag1": true,
     "flag2": false
    },
    ...
]
```

You haven't shown what `Service` should look like, so I've just used `{}` above; it looks like it would be an object. The `...` in the `serviceList` isn't literal, it's meant to indicate you'll probably repeat the thing above it.

So pulling those all together into a single JSON document:

```
{
    "company":     {"Name": "the name", "Id": "the ID"},
    "user":        {"Name": "the name", "Age": "the age"},
    "serviceList": [
        {
         "service": {},
         "mode": "the mode",
         "flag1": true,
         "flag2": false
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Again, the `..` in the `serviceList` is not literal, it indicates that you'll probably repeat the object above it.

---

You edited your question to add the

> I have tried something like;

and the following. As you can tell from my original answer, I'd say the `serviceList` would be an array, not a single object, because `List` generally means exactly that: A list of something, which in JSON would be an array. You've also used lower-case identifiers where whatever it is you're quoting that you have to replicate is using initially-capped identifiers. JSON is case-sensitive, so that could be a problem.

Comment: Given "service" is a list of objects, would it be better to use an array [] instead of an object?

Comment: @booyaa: There's nothing to suggest that "service" is a list of objects. "serviceList" is a list, and I've used an array for it; we don't know anything about "service" except that it looks like it's an object (`Service service` is all we have to work with).